# Get current route matcher in controller scope

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Something like:

```
get '/1.0/users/:id'
  puts current_route_matcher.to_s # '/1.0/users/:id'
end
```

Need to get it to build stats per resource type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
require 'sinatra'

get "/foo/:id" do
  p __method__ #=> :"HEAD /foo/:id"
end

get "/foo/:id/test/:blah" do
  p __method__ #=> :"HEAD /foo/:id/test/:blah"
end
```

Comment: You're right. The block is binded as an instance method on the invoker object https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/lib/sinatra/base.rb#L1106.

Answer (score 0):

You have access to Racks `env.request` object here.

If you accessed http://yoursite.com/foo/bar

```
request.url   #=> http://yoursite.com/foo/bar  
request.path  #=> /foo/bar
```

More about [Rack::Request](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html)

Comment: I think he wants to get the matcher, not the uri.